# TypeScript default constant export

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

We have a TypeScript library that we are publishing to a private NPM environment and we want to use that library in other TS, ES6 or ES5 projects.

Let the library be an npm package named `foo`, its main file works as a barrel doing the following:

```
// Index.ts
import Foo from './Core/Foo';

export {default as Foo} from './Core/Foo';

const foo = new Foo();

export default foo;
```

We want to export the main library class as well as a default instance for apps to use it without creating a new one unless necessary.

Also, we created the type definition files in a separate repository in a similar way to DefinitelyTyped:

```
// foo.d.ts
declare namespace Foo {
  export class Foo {
    public constructor()
    // ...methods
  }

  const foo: Foo;

  export default foo;
}

declare module 'foo' {
  export = Foo;
}
```

Running the tests for it fails with `error TS1063: An export assignment cannot be used in a namespace.`

What I'm aiming for is to have the usage of the default instance like this:

```
// ES5, browser env
window.Foo.foo.someMethod();

// ES6/TS
import foo from 'foo';

foo.someMethod();
```

Any ideas if there is a right way to do this?

**EDIT**

Declaring just the module as @daniel-rosenwasser suggested worked before, but there was a problem when we tried to create a new module that extended the first.

For instance:

```
// bar.d.ts
/// <reference path="../foo/foo.d.ts"/>

import {
  Foo
} from 'foo';

declare module 'bar' {
  export class Bar extends Foo {
    public constructor();
    // more methods
  }
}
```

And its tests:

```
// bar-tests.ts
/// <reference path="../foo/foo.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./bar.d.ts"/>

import foo, {
  Foo
} from 'foo';

import {
  Bar
} from 'bar';

namespace TestBar {
  {
    let result: Foo;
    result = foo;
  }

  {
    let result: Foo;
    result = new Bar();
  }
}
```

The errors this time are:

```
bar/bar-tests.ts: error TS2307: Cannot find module 'bar'.
bar/bar.d.ts: error TS2664: Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'bar' cannot be found.
```

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941420/4378475

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message here is wrong, so I opened up an issue for you: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11092

If you have an ES-style module, you should define it directly in the ambient module declaration:

```
declare module "foo" {
    export class Foo {
        public constructor()
        // ...methods
    }

    const foo: Foo;

    export default foo;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I had before, but the problem came later when I tried to create a new module that extends this one, will add the sample to the question...

Comment: When in another module, the `declare module "foo" {}` syntax creates a *module augmentation*. The *reason* that you're in another module is that you have a top-level import. You can move the import *into* the `declare module `"bar"` to make it work correctly.

Comment: This worked! I did not realize the import statements should go inside the module declaration, thanks Daniel!